# Thunderbolt 3 hotplug in linux freezes the UI

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, thunderbolt

I have Lenovo Thinkpad T480s and [Think Pad Thunderbolt 3 Dock](https://support.lenovo.com/cz/en/solutions/acc100356) connected via thunderbolt 3. The docking station has two external monitors connected via display ports. I have installed [KDE neon](https://neon.kde.org/). The docking station and the laptop usually always connected. When I unplug the docking station everything is working fine, but when plug it back the UI freezes and only reboot can help. I believe the problem is somewhere in the graphical stack, because when I switch to virtual console and do the same everything works as expected.

Some logs:

[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/X4csi7H2)

[xorg.log](https://pastebin.com/nKqQiVde)

Answer (score -1):

I installed 4.20.6 mainline kernel and everything works as expected.